# SwiftUI: how to pass an array to a View to be used in ForEach

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-foreach, swiftui-state

I would like to pass an array of elements to a View and show the elements with a ForEach. When I pass an array of a different size than the previous one, it crashes with error `Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range` on line `Text(elements[$0])`.

My code is like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    private let arrays = [["One", "Two", "Three"], ["Four", "Five"]]
    @State private var selectedArray = 0

    var body: some View {
        AnotherView(elements: arrays[selectedArray])

        Picker("Select Array", selection: $selectedArray) {
            ForEach(arrays.indices) {
                Text("Array \($0)")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct AnotherView: View {
    var elements: [String]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(elements.indices) {
                Text(elements[$0])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ForEach(_:content:)` should only be used for *constant* data. Instead conform data to `Identifiable` or use `ForEach(_:id:content:)` and provide an explicit `id`!

Try this:

```
struct AntorherView: View {

    var elements: [String]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(elements, id:\.self) { i in
                Text(i)
            }
        }
    }
}
```